# How to change BMR Calculator output to round up number?

Tags: java

My home work is: Need to calculate how many bars of choco to maintain woman & man's BMR. I want to change the final output without so many decimal points but round it up or better suggestion. I also understand that there are formats for strings, substring, characters etc. Just don't know how to use them correctly. Not asking for answers, just guidance or show me examples will be helpful. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class BMR 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        int age; 
        double weight, height, BMRw, BMRm; 

        System.out.println("Enter weight in lbs:"); 
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in); 
        weight = kb.nextDouble(); 

        System.out.println("Enter height in inches:"); 
        height = kb.nextDouble(); 

        System.out.println("Enter age in years:");  
        age = kb.nextInt(); 

        BMRw = 655 + (4.3 * weight) + (4.7 * height) - (4.7 * age); 
        BMRm = 66 + (6.3 * weight) + (12.9 * height) - (6.8 * age); 

        System.out.println("BMR for woman is: " + BMRw); 
        System.out.println("BMR for man is: " + BMRm);  

        System.out.println("A typical Chocolate Bar contains about 230 calories");  

        System.out.println("No. of Chocolate Bars consumed to maintain your weight: "); 
        int choco = 230; 

        System.out.println(BMRw / choco); 
        System.out.println(BMRm / choco);   
   } 
}
```

**Out put** is: 
    Enter weight in lbs: 
    118 
    Enter height in inches: 
    5.5 
    Enter age in years: 
    33 
    BMR for woman is: 1033.15 
    BMR for man is: 655.95 
    A typical Chocolate Bar contains about 230 calories 
    No. of Chocolate Bars consumed to maintain your weight: 
     **4.491956521739131** 
     **2.8519565217391305**

Answer (score 0):

Use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00000");
df.format(4.491956521739131);// your number.
```

Comment: I haven't learnt that format, therefore, not appropriate to use on my exercise. Is there a string format or something? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.round()
("BMR for woman is: " + Math.round(BMRw))